# copy-and-swap idiom confusion

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this fully working copy-and-swap idiom in a stack using a linked list.

```
//first is the pointer to the recently added node
//n is the size of the stack
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack&& s) {
    Stack<T> copy{s};
    std::swap(copy.n,n);
    std::swap(copy.first,first);
    return *this;
}
```

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), std::swap "Exchanges the given values." So I thought why not swap the whole values of the two stacks, why just it's items?

```
template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<T>::operator=(Stack&& s) {
    Stack<T> copy{s};
    std::swap(copy, *this);
    return *this;
}
```

Why is it undefined?

Comment: Considering that `s` is an rvalue reference, "copy-and-swap" is needlessly inefficient. "Move-construct-and-swap" would be better: `Stack copy{std::move(s)}; ...`. An idiomatic "copy-and-swap" assignment operator accepts its parameter by value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've introduced infinite recursion. The assignment operator is one of the constructs that `std::swap` uses under the hood, so your `operator=` would call `swap` which would call `operator=` which would call `swap` which would call `operator=` which would call `swap` which would call `operator=` which would call `swap` which would call `operator=` which would call `swap` which would call `operator=` which would call `swap` which would call `operator=` Segmentation fault

Comment: Stack Overflow, actually. On Linux, that's a segfault, but it might lead to other errors as well.

Comment: @rubenvb Stack Overflow is not the message that would be printed on any implementation I know of, though.

Comment: You have a very small stack here, Sir. ;)

Answer (score 4):

As hvd explained, using `std::swap()` inside `operator =` can lead to infinite recursion.

However, if your class implements a proper swap() member function that does not invoke `operator =` on the class then there is no such danger. In this case the operator can safely be implemented in the terms of copy construction.

```
Stack<T>(source).swap(*this);
```